# Activity button visible when Listview checkbox check?

Tags: android-fragments

Like this image
please help me. Thanks in Advance

Submit button visible when List view Checkbox check

Comment: What image?  When adding the image could you also add some code and highlight any errors you are getting?

Comment: no I can not give any error but I have no getting idea where I am doing code like list view Listener or other.
image like submit button